# How to extract all or selected email and email attachments out of the PST files into a local folder?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, eml, pst

I am using [java-libpst](https://github.com/rjohnsondev/java-libpst) to see what emails and email attachments are in there. Now please suggest a way to extract `all`or `selected email` and email attachments out of the PST files into a local folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like the library makes any attempt to map what's in the PST file to internet standard formats such as MIME.  It just seems to model exactly what's in the PST file, leaving it up to you to convert it to MIME if that's what you want.  It looks like all the data you need is there, so it's just a [Simple Matter of Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming).  :-)